# how to access object methods of objects in vue

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to get all the keys from an object in Vue.

I already know to do this in JavaScript. i.e;

```
const object1 = {
    a: 'somestring',
    b: 42,
    c: false
};

console.log(Object.keys(object1));
```

The output would be an array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

How would you do this in a methods in Vue ?

```
methods: {
    getKeys(object1){
        ...
    },
},
```

And explain how would you confront other differences like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the method to an event:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    object1: {
      a: 'somestring',
      b: 42,
      c: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getKeys(object) {
      console.log(Object.keys(object));
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="getKeys(object1)">getkeys</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah OK, I didn't realize how straightforward it is . Over complicated it.